# How to display DIV after 30 seconds on copy text content on web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` tag that I want to display 30 seconds after copying content on a web page. Below is the code.

***Content To Be Copied:***

```
<div class="copy">Copy This Conent</div>
```

***Div Tag To DIsplay After 30sec of Copying:***

```
<div id="dsply">The Content Has Been Copied</div>
```

A good solution to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) event and setTimeout:

```html
<div class="copy">Copy This Conent</div>
<div id="hdsply"><span class="light" style="font-size: 18px">Waiting Syntax Initialization From CMD Console</span></div>
<div id="dsply">The Content Has Been Copied</div>
<div id="dsply1">You Can now proceed</div>



<script>
      const copy = document.querySelector('div.copy');
      const consoleMsg = document.querySelector('div#hdsply');
      const display = document.querySelector('div#dsply');
      const displayProgress = document.querySelector('div#dsply1');
  
      display.style.display = 'none';
      displayProgress.style.display = 'none';

      copy.addEventListener('copy', event => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          display.style.display = 'block';
          displayProgress.style.display = 'block';
          consoleMsg.style.display = 'none';          
        }, 30000);
        event.preventDefault();
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried your code but its idplaying the hiden content on load instead of hidding it and waiting for the copy event to happen before displaying after 30 second. Below is the copy of my js handing the hide function maybe it will assist on helping me better. Thanks in advance


 $(function(){

 $('#dsply').hide();

 setTimeout(function(){
 $('#dsply').fadeIn('slow');
 },30000);

});

Comment: To explain better kindly review my codes below:

On Copy:
<div class="copy">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
document.write
</div>

Show div 30sec after copy:
 <div id="dsply">
 <button id="trigger">
 <div class="content__wrapper">
 <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Begin Handler Process">
 </button>
</div>

JS Function:
 $(function(){
 $('#dsply').hide();
 setTimeout(function(){
 $('#dsply').fadeIn('slow');
 },30000);
});

Comment: Yes I tried this and it worked after utting the code in order. Thank you so much I really appreciate but how can I make this affect more than one div ID Let's say, I have another two divs: <div id="dsply">The Content Has Been Copied</div> and <div id="dsply1">You Can now proceed</div>

Comment: I've updated the answer to hide the new div mentioned

Comment: Thank You so much. It worked. I have mone more question pls.
I have the div tag:
<div id="hdsply"><span class="light" style="font-size: 18px">Waiting Syntax Initialization From CMD Console</span></div>

Controlled by:
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
setTimeout(function() { $("#hdsply").fadeOut(1500); }, 30000)

})
 </script>

This control the div tag to automatically disappear 30 seconds after the #dsply and dsply1 appear.

Comment: My question is, how can I also make the #hdsply disappear 30 seconds after the #copy content has been copied in vice versa of the #dsply and #dsply1?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I hope you understand my question. I mean that I also want the distag #hdsply to auto hide 30secs after copy event while the #display and #display1 shows up.

Comment: I just checked the code now but it's not working. I want the #hdply div tag to also automatically hide 30scons afer copy event or immediatly after the #dsply and #dspy1 div tag shows up

Comment: I didn't see the other div#hdsply, I've updated the answer again.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked but after some time the #dsply #dsply2 also hides it self automatically but I don't want this to happen. I only want the #hdsply to hide while the #dsply #dsply2 shows. I don't want the #dsply #dsply2 to hide it self automatically. Please kindly review thw new code.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207120/discussion-between-chl-security-and-tiagolisalves).

Comment: Please what will the code look like if I want the hide and showing of the div tags to happen without copy event?

Comment: We could continue on chat. No problem.

Comment: Please kindly asnwer my last question

Answer (score 0):

a little js to the rescue:

```js
setTimeout(myFunction, 30000);

function myFunction(){
var dsp = document.getElementById('dsply');
dsp.style.display='block';
}
```

```css
#dsply{
display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="copy">Copy This Conent</div>

<div id="dsply">The Content Has Been Copied</div>
```

Comment: Inaccurate, once the page is running the code will start the clock and if you copy after 30 second it will show right away.

Comment: Thank you for the approach but I have a working code to display hidden content already which runs without copy activity on the web page but I typically need a cope for display that run 30second only after copy activity is done on the web page. I don't want the hidden content to show without copy activity being accried out as instructed in web page.

Comment: I mean something like:

on_copy on web page 
setTimeout(myFunction, 30000);

function myFunction(){
var dsp = document.getElementById('dsply');
dsp.style.display='block';
}